# How can you compare changes in a shifting population over time?

Tags: repeated-measures, proportion, population

How can you compare changes in shifting population over time?

For instance, say I have the proportion of retired people in a town at time 1 (T1), then again at time 2 (T2). The "population" has shifted as some retired people have died or left, some have entered as newly retired or retired people who moved in, and the overall number of people living in that community may have changed.

I don't think this is simply a repeated measures problem due to the population technically being different at each timepoint, but the proportion at T2 will obviously have a lot of overlap with T1. I'd like to be able to say something about whether the proportion of retired people in this area was significantly different at T1 vs T2 (or say, look at a certain neighbourhood in the town and make claims about whether the proportions of retired people in that neighbourhood has changed over time).

Any help on how to think about/approach this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: First: is this an ecological design, or a panel study? For instance, we did radio advertising for cancer screening in one region and not another, then we looked at rates of screening over time in the two regions. But we didn't know who screened - and who didn't - nor who heard the ad (or not).

Comment: I'm kind of interested in both situations. Where you a) only know the proportions but don't know the fate of the individual people measured at both timepoints and b) where you do have panel individual-level data at both timepoints where some people are in both datasets and some people aren't (for the purposes of this example, lets just assume you know the fate of everyone in the community i.e. that they left, died, entered etc.)